# Rota sem autenticação Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Bom dia

Estou precisando liberar um serviço REST num sistema com autenticação, no Laravel 5.1, por isso quando eu acesso o endereço REST num lugar que não esteja autenticado ele pede para inserir login e senha, mas esse serviço não vai precisar de autenticação, pois será usado por um outro sistema da nossa própria empresa para pequenas consultas.

Tem como liberar uma rota no Laravel que não passe pela autenticação que já existe? Tudo que eu tento fazer o sistema encaminha para a página de login e senha para autenticar, antes de poder usar o serviço.

Desde já agradeço

Comment: Voces estao verificando autenticacao no arquivo routes.php? tem como postar um exemplo de rota que você esta usando?

Comment: Acredito que seja alguma classe que é estendida pelo controller, não consegui investigar mais à fundo. Não creio que seja feito na rota, porque no route.php há rotas como essa, que mesmo assim pede autenticação: Route::get('/teste', ['as' => 'client.teste', 'uses' => 'ClientController@teste']);

Comment: Verifica se no constructor do controller ou do extended parent  vocês fazem uso do middleware, como por exemplo: $this->middleware('auth');

Comment: A rota que você precisa liberar está dentro de algum grupo de rotas (Route::group()) ?

Comment: Jao Assy, não achei esse uso do middleware, mas por causa dele consegui descobrir a classe RedirectIfAuthenticated.php, em App/Http/Middleware que nesse caso estava controlando as exceções de autenticação.
Valeu mesmo

Answer (score 2):

Caso a autenticação seja feita através do middleware

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth.basic'], function() {

  //Rotas autenticadas

});

  //Rotas não autenticadas

Route::get('approve', ['as' => 'approve', 'uses' => 'Web\CustomerCardController@approve_customer_card']);
```